# Why do C compilers not warn when assigning integer value too high for signed type?

Tags: c, integer, unsigned-integer

(assuming 64bit machine)

e.g.

```
int n = 0xFFFFFFFF; //max 32bit unsigned number
printf("%u\n", n);
```

The maximum positive number that a regular signed integer (32bit) can store is `0x7FFFFFFF`.

In the above example I'm assigning the maximum *unsigned* integer value to a regular signed integer, I'm receiving no warnings or error from GCC, and the result is printed without problems (with `-Wall -Wextra`).

Appending `U` or `L` to the hex constant changes nothing.

Why is that?

Comment: Because that is a valid int value.

Comment: `0xFFFFFFFF` is not a signed or unsigned value, but the hexadecimal representation of a bit pattern, which is meaningful in its context.

Comment: The value is not too high, `0XFFFFFFFF` is filling all the bits of the `int`

Comment: @WeatherVane `0xFFFFFFFF` has a type...

Comment: @EugeneSh. go on...

Comment: @WeatherVane It is an integer constant. Signed or unsigned depending on the implementation

Comment: @EugeneSh. conversely using the `printf` format specifier `%X` does not output any sign, only the hex representation of the bits in the value passed.

Comment: For a signed 32-bit integer, the value 0xFFFFFFFF is a -1 (2's complement) which is valid.   Even if it was out of range, C doesn't do any range checking (that I know of); values are just truncated.   This makes compiled C code fast.  The burden is put on the developer to write correct code or range check when needed.

Comment: The actual value of `n` here is implementation defined. If `int` is 32-bit long, then the type of `0xFFFFFFFF` is `unsigned int` (see [here](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.1p4)). Then converted to `int` the result is [implementation defined](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.3p3). Printing `int` as `%x` or `%u` is undefined behavior.

Comment: There's no meaningful answer to the main question. This is a genuine case for a warning. The compilers should warn.

Comment: Per C 2011 (N1570) 6.4.4.1 paragraph 5, the type of a hexadecimal constant without a suffix is the first of the following that can represent its value: `int`, `unsigned int`, `long int`, `unsigned long int`, `long long int`, and `unsigned long long int`. Thus, in a C implementation in which `int` has 32 value bits, `0xFFFFFFFF` is an `unsigned int`. In a C implementation in which `int` has 64 value bits, `0xFFFFFFFF` is an `int`.

Comment: @Marker incorrect-o. The standard doesn't specify truncation, 2's complement or anything such. The last sentence is mostly true.

Comment: @WeatherVane `0xFFFFFFFF` is an unsigned integer constant. C assignment has value semantics, the representation does not matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that `int` and `unsigned int` are 32 bits, which is the case on most platforms you're likely to be using (both 32-bit and 64-bit systems). Then the constant `0xFFFFFFFF` is of type `unsigned int`, and has the value 4294967295.

This:

```
int n = 0xFFFFFFFF;
```

implicitly converts that value from `unsigned int` to `int`. The result of the conversion is implementation-defined; there is no undefined behavior. (In principle, it can also cause an implementation-defined signal to be raised, but I know of no implementations that do that).

Most likely the value stored in `n` will be `-1`.

```
printf("%u\n", n);
```

Here you use a `%u` format specifier, which requires an argument of type `unsigned int`, but you pass it an argument of type `int`. The standard says that values of corresponding signed and unsigned type are interchangeable as function arguments, but *only* for values that are within the range of both types, which is not the case here.

This call does not perform a conversion from `int` to `unsigned int`. Rather, an `int` value is passed to `printf`, which *assumes* that the value it received is of type `unsigned int`. The behavior is undefined. (Again, this would be a reasonable thing to warn about.)

The most likely result is that the `int` value of `-1`, which (assuming 2's-complement) has the same representation as `0xFFFFFFFF`, will be treated as if it were an `unsigned int` value of `0xFFFFFFFF`, which is printed in decimal as `4294967295`.

You can get a warning on `int n = 0xFFFFFFFF;` by using the `-Wconversion` or `-Wsign-conversion` option. These option are not included in `-Wextra` or `-Wall`. (You'd have to ask the gcc maintainers why.)

I don't know of an option that will cause a warning on the `printf` call.

(Of course the fix is to define `n` as an `unsigned int`, which makes everything correct and consistent.)

Answer (score 4):

`0xFFFFFFFF`, on a platform where `unsigned` has a maximum value of 2<sup>32</sup>-1, will have the type `unsigned` according to "6.4.4.1 Integer Constants" of the Standard.

And then we get to the conversion:

> #### 6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers
>
> 1 When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than _Bool, if the value can be represented by the new type, it is unchanged.
>   2 Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type.60)
>   3 Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-deﬁned or an implementation-deﬁned signal is raised.

So, the result is implementation-defined or raises an implementation-defined signal.

Now, you print your `int` with the format `%u`, which is just plain mismatched. And while that is strictly speaking UB, you will likely get the original constant, assuming you have 2s-complement and the original assignment used wrap-around.

Answer (score 4):

The C standard doesn't specify the behaviour but requires that the implementation specifies it. [*GCC* always uses 2's complement representation and converts via truncation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integers-implementation.html), therefore `int32_t i = 0xFFFFFFFF;` will result in `i` being set to -1 when compiled with GCC. On other compilers YMMV.

---

To get the warning from GCC you need to give the [`-Wsign-conversion` flag](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/NewWconversion):

```
% gcc 0xfffffff.c -c -Wsign-conversion                         
0xfffffff.c:1:9: warning: conversion of unsigned constant value to negative integer
        [-Wsign-conversion]
 int i = 0xFFFFFFFF;
         ^~t ~~~~~~~~
```

In general C compilers by default produce warnings only about very blatant errors and of constraint violations. The `-Wsign-conversion` would make many compilations very noisy - even those that are well-defined, like:

```
unsigned char c = '\x80';
```

which produces

```
unsignedchar.c:1:19: warning: negative integer implicitly converted to unsigned type
         [-Wsign-conversion]
 unsigned char c = '\x80';
                   ^~~~~~
```

on implementations where `char` is signed.

Comment: `unsigned char c = '\x80';` also invokes implementation-defined behaviour. `128` is out of range of the execution character set on this system which is -128 through +127.  (C11 6.4.4.4/10). So I would consider that example to be in the same category as the original one: implementation-defined , but always works as expected, for a suitable definition of "always".

Comment: @M.M it is 5AM here, I guess what I meant that the conversion from `int` is well-defined